# How to set a custom col-id for a grouped column in ag-grid?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

How to set a custom col-id for a grouped column in ag-grid ? currently ag-grid sets “ag-Grid-AutoColumn” as the default id

`<div class="ag-header-cell ag-header-cell-sortable" role="presentation" col-id="ag-Grid-AutoColumn" style="width: 260px; left: 0px;">`

export const getGroupColumn = ({ someprops }) => ({
    id: 'Name',
    title:'Name',
    field: 'status',
    checkboxSelection: true,
    resizable: true,
    sortable: true,
    autoHeight: true,
    minWidth: 300,
    innerRenderer: GroupTitleRenderer,
    params: {
        someprops,
    }
});

Comment: please change the title and place the problem description inside the body of the post. Ag-grid uses classes for library UI styling & actions. You should not change it but probably add a custom class to HTML node element. Any particular reason why you need to change the class?

Comment: @kamil-kubicki done